# TikZ Calendar Rename Months

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calendar

I have created a custom calendar for myself by using tikz picture.
I want to rename the months in *Turkish*.

```
Ocak, \c{S}ubat, Mart, Nisan, May{\i}s, Haziran, Temmuz, A\u{g}ustos, Eyl\"{u}l, Ekim, Kas{\i}m, Aral{\i}k
```

I could **not** find any place where the names of the months are stored.
Thus, I need your help.
Here is my minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[column sep=1em, row sep=1em]{
  \calendar (m09) [dates=2018-09-01 to 2018-09-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m10) [dates=2018-10-01 to 2018-10-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m11) [dates=2018-11-01 to 2018-11-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m12) [dates=2018-12-01 to 2018-12-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m01) [dates=2019-01-01 to 2019-01-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m02) [dates=2019-02-01 to 2019-02-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m03) [dates=2019-03-01 to 2019-03-last,week list,month label above centered]; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Warning:

This is a hackish solution, not a good one.

---

The `calendar` library uses the `\translate` command (from the `translator` package) around the month names, so you should, in principle, only have to load the `translator` package with your language option. I couldn't get it to work...

So you can redefine the `\pgfcalendarmonthname` to suit your needs:

```
\def\pgfcalendarmonthname#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or Ocak\or \c{S}ubat\or Mart\or Nisan\or
  May{\i}s\or Haziran\or Temmuz\or A\u{g}ustos\or
  Eyl\"{u}l\or Ekim\or Kas{\i}m\or Aral{\i}k\fi
}
```

full MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\def\pgfcalendarmonthname#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or Ocak\or \c{S}ubat\or Mart\or Nisan\or
  May{\i}s\or Haziran\or Temmuz\or A\u{g}ustos\or
  Eyl\"{u}l\or Ekim\or Kas{\i}m\or Aral{\i}k\fi
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every calendar/.style = { week list,month label above centered },
  fullmonth/.style = {
    dates = #1-01 to #1-last
  },
]
\matrix[column sep=1em, row sep=1em]{
  \calendar (m09) [fullmonth = 2018-09]; &
  \calendar (m10) [fullmonth = 2018-10]; &
  \calendar (m11) [fullmonth = 2018-11]; &
  \calendar (m12) [fullmonth = 2018-12]; &
  \calendar (m01) [fullmonth = 2019-01]; &
  \calendar (m02) [fullmonth = 2019-02]; &
  \calendar (m03) [fullmonth = 2019-03]; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

If you prefer to write the month name manually, you can use the `month text` option to achieve the same result:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every calendar/.style = { week list,month label above centered },
  fullmonth/.style = {
    dates = #1-01 to #1-last
  },
]
\matrix[column sep=1em, row sep=1em]{
  \calendar (m09) [fullmonth=2018-09, month text = {Eyl\"{u}l}]; &
  \calendar (m10) [fullmonth=2018-10, month text = {Ekim}]; &
  \calendar (m11) [fullmonth=2018-11, month text = {Kas{\i}m}]; &
  \calendar (m12) [fullmonth=2018-12, month text = {Aral{\i}k}]; &
  \calendar (m01) [fullmonth=2019-01, month text = {Ocak}]; &
  \calendar (m02) [fullmonth=2019-02, month text = {\c{S}ubat}]; &
  \calendar (m03) [fullmonth=2019-03, month text = {Mart}]; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to type the months manually into the matrix at aproopriate places?

Comment: @bkarpuz Yes, it is. See my edit.

Comment: Oh not like that, I mean without defining \pgfcalendarmonthname. By typing the month names at matrix nodes manually.

Comment: @bkarpuz Drat, I messed up the edit. Now it's the way it should be.